# How can I return a single character from the console in a batch script without pressing enter?

Tags: dos, batch-file

I'd like to read/return a single character from a batch script without having to hit the enter key, like `getChar()` in C/C++. How would I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [CHOICE](http://www.computerhope.com/choicehl.htm) command

Example borrowed from [this site](http://www.infionline.net/~wtnewton/batch/batchfaq.html)

```
   @echo off
   :menu
   cls
   echo.
   echo       A - Text for item A
   echo       B - Text for item B
   echo       C - End
   echo.
   choice /c:ABC > nul
   if errorlevel 3 goto end
   if errorlevel 2 goto B
   if errorlevel 1 goto A
   echo Error... choice not installed
   goto end
   :A
   echo Commands for item A
   pause
   goto menu
   :B
   echo Commands for item B
   pause
   goto menu
   :end
```

Comment: This seems to need the enter key on Windows 7 but it's still useful.

Comment: @Ant That is strange, I tested it on my Win7 system and it works as advertized, no enter needed. Are you sure the enter key you have to hit isn't caused by the "pause" commands?

Comment: Oh, it is my environment. I'm running in a shell in the Epsilon editor. It's fine in a DOS box.